# Can an ASP.NET MVC2 site have an optional enum route parameter? If so, can we default that value if not provided?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, enums, routes

can I have a route like...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Boundaries-Show",
    "Boundaries",
     new 
     {
         controller = "Boundaries", 
         action = "Show",
         locationType = UrlParameter.Optional
     });
```

Where the action method is...

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Show(int? aaa, int? bbb, LocationType locationType) { ... }
```

and if the person doesn't provide a value for `locationType` .. then it defaults to `LocationType.Unknown`.

Is this possible?

#### Update #1

I've stripped back the action method to contain ONE method (just until I get this working). It now looks like this ..

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Show(LocationType locationType = LocationType.Unknown) { .. }
```

.. and I get this error message...

> The parameters dictionary contains an
>   invalid entry for parameter
>   'locationType' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Show(MyProject.Core.LocationType)' in
>   'MyProject.Controllers.GeoSpatialController'.
>   The dictionary contains a value of
>   type 'System.Int32', but the parameter
>   requires a value of type
>   'MyProject.Core.LocationType'.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Is it thinking that the optional route parameter `LocationType` is an int32 and not a custom `Enum` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can supply a default value like so:

```
public ActionResult Show(int? aaa, int? bbb, LocationType locationType = LocationType.Unknown) { ... }
```

**UPDATE:**

Or if you are using .NET 3.5:

```
public ActionResult Show(int? aaa, int? bbb, [DefaultValue(LocationType.Unknown)] LocationType locationType) { ... }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
public ActionResult Show(int? aaa, int? bbb, int locationType = 0) {
  var _locationType = (LocationType)locationType;
}

public enum LocationType {
    Unknown = 0,
    Something = 1
}
```

Comment: For .NET 4.0. MVC 2 is also available in 3.5.

Comment: Which way is more a 'standard' ?

Comment: @Pure.Krome The new way (4.0) is more readable and thus prefered imho.

Comment: @Fabian - do i still need to define the parameter as optional in my global.asax route registration? what about the 2 nullable ints? mark them as optional in the route registration also?

Comment: @Pure.Krome yes you still need to define it as optional, because the parameter wont be present but the route still has to match. You can define those 2 optional and give them a default value aswell if you require this.

Comment: @Fabian - I've updated the opening post with an update / error message.

Comment: Intresting, it is most likely serializing that to an int. I guess the only way of doing it by casting, updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the DefaultValue attribute to your action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Show(int? aaa, int? bbb, [DefaultValue(LocationType.Unknown)]LocationType locationType) { ... }
```

or use optional parameters depending on what language version your using:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Show(int? aaa, int? bbb, LocationType locationType = LocationType.Default) { ... }
```